# Typescript: How to strongly-type a function that transforms a map of functions into similar functions with a different type param?

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm trying to strongly-type a `globalizeSelectors` function that would transform a map of redux selector functions such that they will accept a `GlobalState` type instead of their StateSlice type based on the key of their StateSlice (where StateSlice means it's a value of one of the GlobalState object's properties).

The tricky part is that the return types of the selectors can all be different, and I don't quite know how to type that variation (or if it's even possible). Based on the typescript docs, I'm guessing this might involve some clever use of the `infer` operator, but my typescript-fu isn't quite at that level yet.

Here's what I've got so far:
(BTW, for you reduxy types, nevermind the fact that these selectors don't handle props or additional args -- I've removed that to simplify this a bit)

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash'

// my (fake) redux state types
type SliceAState = { name: string }
type SliceBState = { isWhatever: boolean }

type GlobalState = {
  a: SliceAState;
  b: SliceBState;
}

type StateKey = keyof GlobalState

type Selector<TState, TResult> = (state: TState) => TResult

type StateSlice<TKey extends StateKey> = GlobalState[TKey]

type GlobalizedSelector<TResult> = Selector<GlobalState, TResult>

const globalizeSelector = <TKey extends StateKey, Result>(
  sliceKey: TKey,
  sliceSelector: Selector<StateSlice<TKey>, Result>
): GlobalizedSelector<Result> => state => sliceSelector(state[sliceKey])

// an example of a map of selectors as they might be exported from their source file
const sliceASelectors = {
  getName: (state: SliceAState): string => state.name,
  getNameLength: (state: SliceAState): number => state.name.length
}

// fake global state
const globalState: GlobalState = {
  a: { name: 'My Name' },
  b: { isWhatever: true }
}

// so this works...
const globalizedGetName = globalizeSelector('a', sliceASelectors.getName)
const globalizedNameResult: string = globalizedGetName(globalState)

const globalizedGetNameLength = globalizeSelector(
  'a',
  sliceASelectors.getNameLength
)
const globalizedNameLengthResult: number = globalizedGetNameLength(globalState)

/* but when I try to transform the map to globalize all its selectors, 
   I get type errors (although the implementation works as untyped
   javascript):
*/
type SliceSelector<TKey extends StateKey, T> = T extends Selector<
  StateSlice<TKey>,
  infer R
>
  ? Selector<StateSlice<TKey>, R>
  : never

const globalizeSelectors = <TKey extends StateKey, T>(
  sliceKey: TKey,
  sliceSelectors: {
    [key: string]: SliceSelector<TKey, T>;
  }
) => mapValues(sliceSelectors, s => globalizeSelector(sliceKey, s))

const globalized = globalizeSelectors('a', sliceASelectors)
/*_________________________________________^ TS Error:
Argument of type '{ getName: (state: SliceAState) => string; getNameLength: (state: SliceAState) => number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'getName' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(state: SliceAState) => string' is not assignable to type 'never'. [2345]
*/
const globalizedGetName2: string = globalized.getName(globalState)
```

Comment: Any thought on the answer ? If you have issues with it let me know and I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `globalizeSelectors` the type `sliceSelectors` is `{[key: string]: SliceSelector<TKey, T> }`. But who should `T` be in this case? In your simple version `T` is going to be the return type of that particular slice selector, but when you map multiple `T` can't be all the return types.

The solution I would use is to use `T` to rerpesent the whole type of `sliceSelectors` with th restriction that all memebers must be of type `SliceSelector<TKey, any>`. The `any` there just represents we don't care what the return type of the slice selectors are.

Even though we don't care what the return type of each slice selector is, `T` will capture the type acturately (ie the return types of each function in the object will not be `any` but the actual type). We can then use `T` to create a mapped type that globalizez each function in the object.

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash'

// my (fake) redux state types
type SliceAState = { name: string }
type SliceBState = { isWhatever: boolean }

type GlobalState = {
  a: SliceAState;
  b: SliceBState;
}

type StateKey = keyof GlobalState


type GlobalizedSelector<TResult> = Selector<GlobalState, TResult>

const globalizeSelector = <TKey extends StateKey, Result>(
  sliceKey: TKey,
  sliceSelector: Selector<StateSlice<TKey>, Result>
): GlobalizedSelector<Result> => state => sliceSelector(state[sliceKey])

// an example of a map of selectors as they might be exported from their source file
const sliceASelectors = {
  getName: (state: SliceAState): string => state.name,
  getNameLength: (state: SliceAState): number => state.name.length
}

// fake global state
const globalState: GlobalState = {
  a: { name: 'My Name' },
  b: { isWhatever: true }
}

type Selector<TState, TResult> = (state: TState) => TResult

type StateSlice<TKey extends StateKey> = GlobalState[TKey]

// Simplified selctor, not sure what the conditional type here was trying to achive
type SliceSelector<TKey extends StateKey, TResult> = Selector<StateSlice<TKey>, TResult>

const globalizeSelectors = <TKey extends StateKey, T extends {
    [P in keyof T]: SliceSelector<TKey, any>
  }>(
  sliceKey: TKey,
  sliceSelectors: T
) : { [P in keyof T]: GlobalizedSelector<ReturnType<T[P]>> } => mapValues(sliceSelectors, s => globalizeSelector(sliceKey, s as any)) as any // Not sure about mapValues 

const globalized = globalizeSelectors('a', sliceASelectors)

const globalizedGetName2: string = globalized.getName(globalState)
```

The only small issue is that `mapValues` needs some type assertions to work, I don't think `mapValues` is equiped to deal with these types.

Comment: Hi Titian, sorry I've been unable to get back to this question, as I've just had a new baby son!  I'll take a good look at this and give it a try.

Comment: @JamesNail congrats on the baby. It's gonna be hard but incredible :-). No worries about the answer, whenever you get to it I'll be around,:-)

Comment: BTW, @titian, I just awarded you the bounty on this question whether or not it works, as I appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: @JamesNail 10x :-). It works as far as I tested it. If you have any issues let me know and we will fix them.